# Junit + Ant + Eclipse unit test attempts to run but always returns 1 execution

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have an ant task that I am running via Eclipse that fails to properly execute the test case.  The output from Ant is as follows:

```
[junit] Running my.custom.test.GoTest   
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 seconds   
[junit] Test my.custom.test.GoTest FAILED
```

Ant script minimum possible:

```
<project>
    <target name="test">  
      <javac srcdir="Test/src" destdir="Test/bin" />  
      <junit fork="true" printsummary="true">  
          <batchtest>   
             <fileset dir="Test/test">  
                 <include name="**/*Test.*"/>  
             </fileset> 
          </batchtest>  
      </junit>  
    </target>  
</project>
```

Java file:

```
package my.custom.test  

public class GoTest  
{  
     @Test
     public void test_1() throws Exception  
     {  
         assertTrue(true);  
     }    
     @Test
     public void test_2() throws Exception  
     {  
         assertFalse(false);  
     } 
}
```

I expect the output above from the ant junit task to produce two tests being run.  However, only one is being run.  I am looking for any reasoning as to why this would happen or if there is a configuration issue that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this exact same issue or something very similar the following change will be of great benefit:

```
<junit fork="true" printsummary="true">    
          <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
          <batchtest>   
             <fileset dir="Test/test">  
                 <include name="**/*Test.*"/>  
             </fileset> 
          </batchtest>  
</junit>
```

This led me to a `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: that's a good way to debug :D the Errors: 1 , looked like something bad had happened